# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания? Нужен ли дефис в заголовке?

Tags: пунктуация, раздельно-дефис

«Будильник-интеллектуал»

Его отличительная черта в том, что он не работает на хозяина, и срабатывает не конкретно в поставленное время. Jawbone Up 24 будит строго в стадии БДГ (быстрого движения глаз). 
Для выполнения этой задачи нужно установить значение интервала от 10 до 30 минут.

Comment: Я бы заменил "стадию БДГ (быстрого движения глаз" на "фазу быстрого сна".

Comment: "Для выполнения этой задачи". ---- Тут какая-то недосказанность. В чем задача? Разбудить в стадии БДГ? Для этого интервал не нужен.

Comment: А еще хотелось бы знать, на кого работает этот гад (Почему гад?  Потому что на хозяина не хочет работать!)

Answer (score 2):

**Будильник-интеллектуал**

**Его отличительная черта в том, что он не работает на хозяина и срабатывает не  в конкретно поставленное время. Jawbone Up 24 будит строго в стадии БДГ (быстрого движения глаз). Для выполнения этой задачи нужно установить значение интервала от 10 до 30 мин**ут.

1) **Кавычки можно не ставить,** так как выражение *интеллектуальный будильник, интеллектуальная техника* широко известны. **Дефис ставится,** так как *интеллектуал* — приложение в постпозиции.

2) **Запятая не ставится,** так как придаточные однородны.

3) Не очень понятно выражение ***он не работает на хозяина.***

4) Не очень понятно последнее сообщение, его желательно дополнить: **Для выполнения этой задачи нужно установить значение интервала от 10 до 30 минут, обозначив момент, начиная с которого вас можно будить.**

**Информация**  https://thequestion.ru/questions/202731/chto-takoe-umnyi-budilnik-i-kak-on-rabotaet

Алгоритм работы всех умных будильников одинаков: вы устанавливаете время, к которому вас надо разбудить, и время, начиная с которого вас можно будить. Если в этот промежуток будильник засекает, что вы ворочаетесь — он сразу вас будит. Если почему-то не засечёт — сработает как обычный будильник, в последний момент.